# Share svg on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I've never used before Facebook API so sorry if question will sounds a bit naive. I have a website which contains one SVG image. This img is manipulated by users through jquery/css (changing colors etc.). I want to add SHARE functionality to that element. so after finishing, user can publish it on his timeline. is it possible?

thanks!

Comment: Nope, that is not possible, Facebook doesn’t allow SVG images to be used for sharing. You could at most share a _link_ to your site where that custom SVG image the will be displayed. And you could look for a library that allows you to take a “screenshot” of an SVG in JPEG or PNG format, then you could use that as thumbnail for the shared link (or post that as a photo directly).

Comment: this is what I fear the most. I assume its not worth to spend so much time on that. thanks for your reply.